# How to check resource/memory leakage in a scala program written for Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I have a Spark program written in Scala. I notice that as a container executes more and more task, it's memory consumption keeps on increasing, until the point where yarn just kills the container. So, there is some resource/memory leakage going on which is not apparent in the code. Is there a way to check for this leakage?

Comment: Did you check yarn log ? Are you using dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: Yes I checked yarn log, but I get no clue from there. And what do you mean by dynamic memory allocation here?

Comment: You need to enable a verbose GC mode to observe your JVM.

Comment: Dealing with YARN can be tricky. While you might think that you have memory leakage in spark you can end up in the following situation http://stackoverflow.com/a/36475604

Comment: @eliasah: Is it possible for a container to run two tasks in parallel, that is, concurrently at the same time. Maybe, that is causing the memory error, as two tasks would require twice as big memory. What is your opinion? Although I've set the number of cores to only 1 for an executor.

Comment: I would setup Ganglia on top of that cluster to validate your hypothesis. Unfortunately, with the information given, I can't add much to what I've already said.